# Showing and hiding details (price, sale price, sku etc)when product variant is selected on details page

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, javascript, js

I currently have price, sku and variant title swapping when clicking between variants on a products details page.

This works with AlpineJS and looks something this.
https://codepen.io/amasci/pen/PoWxbPX

```
<div class="flex-1 p-8" x-data="{
 price: '{{- product.defaultPriceAsCurrency|trim -}}',
 variant: '{{- product.defaultVariant.title|trim -}}',
 sku: '{{- product.defaultSku|trim -}}'
}"

<div class="flex flex-wrap items-center pb-6 mb-12 space-x-8 border-b border-gray-200">
  <div class="text-2xl text-blue-500" x-text="price"></div>
  <div class="mt-1 text-sm  flex items-center space-x-2">
    <span class="text-blue-200" x-text="variant"></span>
    <span class="mx-1 text-gray-200">&bull;</span>
    <span class="text-blue-200" x-text="sku"></span>
  </div>
</div>

{% for variant in product.variants %}
<label class="relative transition cursor-pointer variant-option choice-button focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-blue-500"
       for="{{ variant.id }}"
>
  <input type="radio"
         @click="price='{{- variant.priceAsCurrency|trim -}}', variant='{{- variant.title|trim -}}', sku='{{- variant.sku|trim -}}'"
         id="{{ variant.id }}"
         name="purchasables[1][id]"
         value="{{ variant.id }}"
         class="sr-only"
    {{ loop.first ? 'checked' }}
  >
  <span class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm text-gray-400 border border-gray-300 transition variant-label hover:border-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
    {{ variant.title }}
  </span>
</label>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I have come to now add some functionality for sale prices.
Whereby I would like to show the Price with a strike and the new sale price.

```
{% if variant.onSale %}
  <del class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ variant.priceAsCurrency }}</del>
  <br>{{ variant.salePriceAsCurrency }}
{% else %}
  {{ variant.priceAsCurrency }}
{% endif %}
```

What is the best way to adopt my code to do this?
I cannot pass in the html code to alpine.

Should I just loop the variants and output the code and then show/hide the right block based on which radio is selected or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

So, I actually decided a slightly different approach in the end and not sure if it is better or less performant, but I feel gives me a little more flexibility. Basically,  more like a 'tabbed' approach that shows the right div based on the option selected. This allows me to be a little more flexible with the information and layout I want in that area of the page.

Here is the final code:

```
{% block productVariantSelected %}
  {# Price and Variant SKU #}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <div x-show="selectedVariant === {{ variant.id }}" class="mt-3">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center pb-2 mb-8 space-x-8 border-b border-gray-200">
        {% if variant.onSale %}
          <div class="flex items-center">
            <del class="text-sm text-gray-500 mr-2">{{ variant.priceAsCurrency }}</del>
            <span class="text-blue-500 text-2xl font-semibold">{{ variant.salePriceAsCurrency }}</span>
          </div>
        {% else %}
          <span class="text-blue-500 text-2xl font-semibold">{{ variant.priceAsCurrency }}</span>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="mt-1 text-sm  flex items-center space-x-2">
          <span class="text-blue-200">{{ variant.title }}</span>
          <span class="mx-1 text-gray-200">&bull;</span>
          <span class="text-blue-200">{{ variant.sku }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

<h3 class="mb-3 text-gray-700 uppercase">{{ variantHeading|default('Options') }}</h3>
<div class="flex flex-wrap items-center space-x-3 mb-12">
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <label class="relative transition cursor-pointer variant-option choice-button focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-blue-500"
           for="{{ variant.id }}"
    >
      <input type="radio"
             @click="selectedVariant={{ variant.id }}, variantTitle='{{- variant.title|trim -}}'"
             id="{{ variant.id }}"
             name="purchasables[1][id]"
             value="{{ variant.id }}"
             class="sr-only"
        {{ loop.first ? 'checked' }}
      >
      <span class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm text-gray-400 border border-gray-300 transition variant-label hover:border-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
    {{ variant.title }}
  </span>
    </label>
  {% endfor %}
  
  <div class="text-sm text-gray-400 font-light mb-0 self-center mt-2">
    Can’t find the right size? <a href="{{ siteUrl('contact') }}" class="text-blue-500 underline hover:text-sea-500">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```